# I need to stop theBox

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I need to stop theBox when it moves out of the screeen (500x500)
I dont know how to anyhelp?

```
 <style>
  #box { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: green; }
 </style>
 <script>
 onload = function() {
     var theBox = document.getElementById("box");
     function animate() {
     if ("theBox")
       theBox.style.left = (theBox.offsetLeft+5)+"px";
       theBox.style.top = (theBox.offsetTop+5)+"px";
     }
     setInterval(animate,100);
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box">The box</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a check to see if the next move will take the box up to or over 500. Also, I've added a call to `clearInterval()` when the box stops, to stop the timer.

```
onload = function() {
    var timer;
    var theBox = document.getElementById("box");
    function animate() {
        if(theBox.offsetLeft+5 < 500 && theBox.offsetTop+5 < 500){
            theBox.style.left = (theBox.offsetLeft+5)+"px";
            theBox.style.top = (theBox.offsetTop+5)+"px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }
    timer = setInterval(animate,100);
}
```

Comment: Found it better to use && instead of &&

Comment: What is I want it to bounce @MrCode

Answer (score 0):

I have added and if statement to check if the height of the page is higher than the offset top of the box:

```
 onload = function() {
 var theBox = document.getElementById("box");
 function animate() {
 if ("theBox")
   if(window.innerHeight > (theBox.offsetTop+25)){
      console.log(theBox.offsetTop+5)
      theBox.style.left = (theBox.offsetLeft+5)+"px";
      theBox.style.top = (theBox.offsetTop+5)+"px";
   }
 }
 setInterval(animate,100);
}
```

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dxcki)